# How many permutation matrixes for a $4 \times 4$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

How many permutation matrixes for a $4\times 4$ matrix ? Given an $n \times n$ matrix what is the general way to find the number of permutation matrixes ?

Comment: Do you know the definition of permutation matrices?

Comment: Of course I do. I wanted to know how to derive them ?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is $n!$. See more information in the Wikipedia article on [permutataion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix).

---

You might also want to read this (if you haven't):

https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask